# Laravel 4 place username to URL using routes

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm fairly new to Laravel,so any help and pointers would be appreciated.
I have already created a login and registration procedure. But i have trouble creating routes.My objective is that when a user successfully logs in, i wish to include the username as a url parameter and then output a profile page based on that username.

problem 1:
example:
$UserName = 'seLinux';

- the user name will be placed to the url;
  `www.mydomain.com/seLinux`

a route will then handle this to output a profile page. The route i created is this. but i want to pass it on to a controller instead of creating the method inside the route.

`Route::get('www.domain.com/{user_name}', function($user_name) {`

// problem 2 how do i pass the $user_name to a controller accessing the profile method and not create a loop.

});

any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this in your route:

```
 Route::get('profile/{user_name}', array(
        'uses' => 'UsersController@action'
 ));
```

In the UsersController:

```
public function action($user_name)
{
    //controller functions here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks har2vey. In my controller named UsersController.php file i included a method getProfile(). and in my routes file When i use `Route::controller('method', 'UsersController')` i can simply access the method via url `domain.com/Profile` without the get action. But when i use the code you gave me i have to access the method as 'domain.com/getProfile.' What's the difference?

Comment: Sorry, was simply copy pasting your route code earlier, I've updated it above. With that you should be redirecting user profile via url **domain.com/profile/[username]** cause you shouldn't put route variable after the domain name as it will mask the other routes.